# Film Camera Olympus OM40

Tags: film, olympus, 35mm

Very new to shooting film. This morning I go to take a shot outdoors and the shutter stops halfway and the viewfinder goes black.

It will not let me complete taking the photo. I remove the lens to check and there is a barcode/QR code covering over the screen.

Any idea what this is and what this means I have done? I am eight shots into the roll. Also the camera is 35 years old.

Comment: Can you take a picture (like, with a phone cam) of what you see?

Comment: A picture is worth a thousand words... please upload a photo

Answer (score 1):

Scan the QR code for help :) j/k - that "QR code" is a pattern imprinted on the shutter curtains to help with weighted exposure.

Irrespective of camera model, the problem described is often due to one of the following causes:

- Battery exhausted on an electronic-shutter camera (which the OM-40 is). Try replacing the battery; in some cases removing, resting, and reinserting the battery could also help.
- Accidentally activated a manual mirror-lock up feature (seems the OM-40 hasn't any, though).
- General film-advance/shutter-cocking mechanical confusion that can *in some cases* be cleared up (or worsened...) by *carefully* actuating winder couplings manually - YMMV...

For this specific camera model, there also seems to be a known wear defect called "sticky magnet syndrome" which might (hopefully not) apply here...

Comment: He apparently had eight successful shots, so my money is on an exhausted battery, rather than some mechanical defect that suddenly appeared after eight shots.